# how to strip parent folder name and use just subdirectory names when zipping

Tags: asp.net

filesToInclude list has this data:

```
 c:/temp/folder1/data.1
 c:/temp/folder1/subfolder/data.1
 c:/temp/folder1/subfolder2/data.1
```

The following DotNetZip code stores the whole path starting with /temp/  but I like to store just /folder1/ without /temp/ prefix.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        foreach (var f in filesToInclude)
        {
            zip.AddFile(f);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the directory part as the second argument. This means finding the directory from the full filename, and then stripping the leading part out.

```
String baseDirectory = "c:/temp/";
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach (var f in filesToInclude)
    {
        String directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(f);
        // Consider adding error checking here to make sure that
        // directory really does start with baseDirectory!
        String relative = directory.Substring(baseDirectory.Length);
        zip.AddFile(f, relative);
    }
}
```